# Violation of immutatibility while purging of private data on hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

If private data has a lifespan, and it is purged after this lifespan. Doesn't this violate the fundamental principle of immutability and the core idea of the blockchain. I know that the hash of these private data is stored in the ledger but if a data deletion is occurring then it seems that the core

Answer (score 2):

The private data is not stored on the blockchain, only a hash of the private data is stored on the blockchain. The private data is stored in a side data store that is local to the private data collection members peer. The parties that instantiate the chaincode determine if the private data in the side data store should live forever or have a lifespan based on blockToLive. This is no different than storing the preimage of the private data outside the Fabric network and storing a hash on chain. Fabric simply provides the management and distribution of the private data. In either case, the 'evidence' of the private data on chain is the important aspect for immutability, and this is preserved through the on chain hash.